# Signed application is getting installed without keystore in the device

Tags: android

I am facing one problem regarding installing of signed application in the device.I have generated .apk file of android application using Eclipse IDE(right click on the project > Android Tools > Export Signed Application Package...) and created key store and generated the .apk file. I copied key store and .apk file to the Device SD card and install it, application has installed and working properly then i uninstall the application and removed the key store from the sd card and again install the application(now key store file is not there) in this scenario also application is getting installed and working properly.
My doubt is if application is getting installed without key store also then what is the need of generating the key store or what is the purpose of this key store file?
OR is there something which i am doing wrong in order to generate signed .apk file?

Please do help me resolve this issue.

Regards,
Piks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont have to copy keystore to your device ,In fact you should never expose your key anywhere ..Have a quick look at this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#secure-key)

The Android system uses the certificate as a means of identifying the author of an application and establishing trust relationships between applications.

Importance of signing :

Application upgrade - If you want to provide seamless upgrades you need to sign with same key store.

Application modularity – The Android system allows applications that are signed by the same certificate to run in the same process.

Code/data sharing through permissions – By signing multiple applications with the same certificate and using signature-based permissions checks, your applications can share code and data in a secure manner.

Also Make sure you choose a package name that is suitable over the life of your application.

If you have an application installed in device with some package name and signed with your private key , then system will not allow you to install another application with same package name and signed with some other key.

Comment: okie, I understood what you have described but still i am not able to understand where exactly i should use this key, do i need to share this key to the user who will use the application or is it not required? And what if I publish this application to the android market, do i need to publish this key also OR anyone can use my application without this key?So if i can publish this application without key then can i say that this key is only applicable for development/up gradation purpose of the application?

Comment: As I said earlier, you should never expose your key anywhere ..Have a quick look at this http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#secure-key...Its importance come into picture when you consider Installation security, upgrade maintainance, and data/code sharing

Answer (score 1):

First you don't have to generate a keystore as ADT creates one in `<user_profile>/.android`.

Then you don't need to copy the keystore to your device.